# magento 2 intercept invalid method

Tags: magento2, php, debug

I am getting strange issue.
I removed var folder and loaded the page .but no luck.

I am using marketplace multi-vender extension as you can see in paths.

```
1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException): Invalid method Webkul\Marketplace\Block\Collection\Interceptor::__

Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException): Invalid method Webkul\Marketplace\Block\Collection\Interceptor::__
#0 /home/pocketgrocery/staging.pocketgrocery.com/var/generation/Webkul/Marketplace/Block/Collection/Interceptor.php(1376): Magento\Framework\DataObject->__call('__', Array)
#1 [internal function]: Webkul\Marketplace\Block\Collection\Interceptor->__call('__', Array)
#2 [internal function]: Webkul\Marketplace\Block\Collection\Interceptor->__('There are no pr...')
#3 /home/pocketgrocery/staging.pocketgrocery.com/vendor/magento/framework/View/TemplateEngine/Php.php(82): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#4 /home/pocketgrocery/staging.pocketgrocery.com/app/code/Webkul/Agorae/view/frontend/templates/marketplace/seller_pick_collection.phtml(41): Magento\Framework\View\TemplateEngine\Php->__call('__', Array)
#5 /home/pocketgrocery/staging.pocketgrocery.com/app/code/Webkul/Agorae/view/frontend/templates/marketplace/seller_pick_collection.phtml(41): Magento\Framework\View\TemplateEngine\Php->__('There are no pr...')
#6 /home/pocketgrocery/staging.pocketgrocery.com/vendor/magento/framework/View/TemplateEngine/Php.php(59): include('/home/pocketgro...')
#7 /home/pocketgrocery/staging.pocketgrocery.com/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template.php(255): Magento\Framework\View\TemplateEngine\Php->render(Object(Webkul\Marketplace\Block\Collection\Interceptor), '/home/pocketgro...', Array)
#8 /home/pocketgrocery/staging.pocketgrocery.com/var/generation/Webkul/Marketplace/Block/Collection/Interceptor.php(609): Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->fetchView('/home/pocketgro...')
#9 /home/pocketgrocery/staging.pocketgrocery.com/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template.php(279): Webkul\Marketplace\Block\Collection\Interceptor->fetchView('/home/pocketgro...')
#10 /home/pocketgrocery/staging.pocketgrocery.com/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php(659): Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->_toHtml()
#11 /home/pocketgrocery/staging.pocketgrocery.com/var/generation/Webkul/Marketplace/Block/Collection/Interceptor.php(934): Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->toHtml()
#12 /home/pocketgrocery/staging.pocketgrocery.com/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(542): Webkul\Marketplace\Block\Collection\Interceptor->toHtml()
#13 /home/pocketgrocery/staging.pocketgrocery.com/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(518): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderBlock('agorae_mp_selle...')
#14 /home/pocketgrocery/staging.pocketgrocery.com/var/generation/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(206): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('agorae_mp_selle...')
#15 /home/pocketgrocery/staging.pocketgrocery.com/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(472): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('agorae_mp_selle...')
#16 /home/pocketgrocery/staging.pocketgrocery.com/var/generation/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(193): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('agorae_mp_selle...', true)
#17 /home/pocketgrocery/staging.pocketgrocery.com/app/code/Webkul/Agorae/view/frontend/templates/marketplace/collection_view.phtml(26): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('agorae_mp_selle...')
#18 /home/pocketgrocery/staging.pocketgrocery.com/vendor/magento/framework/View/TemplateEngine/Php.php(59): include('/home/pocketgro...')
#19 /home/pocketgrocery/staging.pocketgrocery.com/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template.php(255): Magento\Framework\View\TemplateEngine\Php->render(Object(Webkul\Marketplace\Block\Collection\Interceptor), '/home/pocketgro...', Array)
#20 /home/pocketgrocery/staging.pocketgrocery.com/var/generation/Webkul/Marketplace/Block/Collection/Interceptor.php(609): Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->fetchView('/home/pocketgro...')
#21 /home/pocketgrocery/staging.pocketgrocery.com/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template.php(279): Webkul\Marketplace\Block\Collection\Interceptor->fetchView('/home/pocketgro...')
#22 /home/pocketgrocery/staging.pocketgrocery.com/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php(659): Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->_toHtml()
#23 /home/pocketgrocery/staging.pocketgrocery.com/var/generation/Webkul/Marketplace/Block/Collection/Interceptor.php(934): Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->toHtml()
#24 /home/pocketgrocery/staging.pocketgrocery.com/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(542): Webkul\Marketplace\Block\Collection\Interceptor->toHtml()
#25 /home/pocketgrocery/staging.pocketgrocery.com/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(518): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderBlock('agorae_mp_colle...')
#26 /home/pocketgrocery/staging.pocketgrocery.com/var/generation/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(206): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('agorae_mp_colle...')
#27 /home/pocketgrocery/staging.pocketgrocery.com/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(472): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('agorae_mp_colle...')
#28 /home/pocketgrocery/staging.pocketgrocery.com/var/generation/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(193): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('agorae_mp_colle...', true)
#29 /home/pocketgrocery/staging.pocketgrocery.com/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(569): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('agorae_mp_colle...')
#30 /home/pocketgrocery/staging.pocketgrocery.com/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(520): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('content')
#31 /home/pocketgrocery/staging.pocketgrocery.com/var/generation/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(206): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('content')
#32 /home/pocketgrocery/staging.pocketgrocery.com/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(472): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('content')
#33 /home/pocketgrocery/staging.pocketgrocery.com/var/generation/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(193): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('content', true)
#34 /home/pocketgrocery/staging.pocketgrocery.com/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(569): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('content')
#35 /home/pocketgrocery/staging.pocketgrocery.com/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(520): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('main')
#36 /home/pocketgrocery/staging.pocketgrocery.com/var/generation/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(206): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('main')
#37 /home/pocketgrocery/staging.pocketgrocery.com/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(472): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('main')
#38 /home/pocketgrocery/staging.pocketgrocery.com/var/generation/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(193): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('main', true)
#39 /home/pocketgrocery/staging.pocketgrocery.com/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(569): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('main')
#40 /home/pocketgrocery/staging.pocketgrocery.com/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(520): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('columns')
#41 /home/pocketgrocery/staging.pocketgrocery.com/var/generation/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(206): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('columns')
#42 /home/pocketgrocery/staging.pocketgrocery.com/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(472): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('columns')
#43 /home/pocketgrocery/staging.pocketgrocery.com/var/generation/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(193): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('columns', true)
#44 /home/pocketgrocery/staging.pocketgrocery.com/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(569): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('columns')
#45 /home/pocketgrocery/staging.pocketgrocery.com/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(520): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('main.content')
#46 /home/pocketgrocery/staging.pocketgrocery.com/var/generation/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(206): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('main.content')
#47 /home/pocketgrocery/staging.pocketgrocery.com/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(472): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('main.content')
#48 /home/pocketgrocery/staging.pocketgrocery.com/var/generation/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(193): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('main.content', true)
#49 /home/pocketgrocery/staging.pocketgrocery.com/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(569): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('main.content')
#50 /home/pocketgrocery/staging.pocketgrocery.com/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(520): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('page.wrapper')
#51 /home/pocketgrocery/staging.pocketgrocery.com/var/generation/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(206): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('page.wrapper')
#52 /home/pocketgrocery/staging.pocketgrocery.com/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(472): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('page.wrapper')
#53 /home/pocketgrocery/staging.pocketgrocery.com/var/generation/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(193): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('page.wrapper', true)
#54 /home/pocketgrocery/staging.pocketgrocery.com/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(569): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('page.wrapper')
#55 /home/pocketgrocery/staging.pocketgrocery.com/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(520): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('root')
#56 /home/pocketgrocery/staging.pocketgrocery.com/var/generation/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(206): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('root')
#57 /home/pocketgrocery/staging.pocketgrocery.com/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(472): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('root')
#58 /home/pocketgrocery/staging.pocketgrocery.com/var/generation/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(193): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('root', true)
#59 /home/pocketgrocery/staging.pocketgrocery.com/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(938): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('root')
#60 /home/pocketgrocery/staging.pocketgrocery.com/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(146): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->getOutput()
#61 /home/pocketgrocery/staging.pocketgrocery.com/var/generation/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(494): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->___callPlugins('getOutput', Array, Array)
#62 /home/pocketgrocery/staging.pocketgrocery.com/vendor/magento/framework/View/Result/Page.php(243): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->getOutput()
#63 /home/pocketgrocery/staging.pocketgrocery.com/vendor/magento/framework/View/Result/Layout.php(164): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page->render(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
#64 /home/pocketgrocery/staging.pocketgrocery.com/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(74): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Layout->renderResult(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
#65 /home/pocketgrocery/staging.pocketgrocery.com/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(70): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->___callParent('renderResult', Array)
#66 /home/pocketgrocery/staging.pocketgrocery.com/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(63): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Framewo...', 'renderResult', Object(Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor), Array, 'result-varnish-...')
#67 /home/pocketgrocery/staging.pocketgrocery.com/vendor/magento/module-page-cache/Model/Controller/Result/VarnishPlugin.php(74): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
#68 /home/pocketgrocery/staging.pocketgrocery.com/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(67): Magento\PageCache\Model\Controller\Result\VarnishPlugin->aroundRenderResult(Object(Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
#69 /home/pocketgrocery/staging.pocketgrocery.com/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Framewo...', 'renderResult', Object(Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor), Array, 'result-builtin-...')
#70 /home/pocketgrocery/staging.pocketgrocery.com/vendor/magento/module-page-cache/Model/Controller/Result/BuiltinPlugin.php(67): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
#71 /home/pocketgrocery/staging.pocketgrocery.com/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(142): Magento\PageCache\Model\Controller\Result\BuiltinPlugin->aroundRenderResult(Object(Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
#72 /home/pocketgrocery/staging.pocketgrocery.com/var/generation/Magento/Framework/View/Result/Page/Interceptor.php(130): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->___callPlugins('renderResult', Array, Array)
#73 /home/pocketgrocery/staging.pocketgrocery.com/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(139): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->renderResult(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
#74 /home/pocketgrocery/staging.pocketgrocery.com/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(258): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
#75 /home/pocketgrocery/staging.pocketgrocery.com/index.php(43): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http))
#76 {main}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to run the compile command.

> php bin/magento setup:di:compile

After installing or after having changes in some in extension codes, you need to run this command. This will accomodate the latest changes and thus create appropriate interceptors.

You are also required to run `setup:upgrade` in case the module is just installed  (in prior to run the compile command)

> php bin/magento setup:upgrade

### EDIT

You need to run compile command in `development` mode too. Please read the 
[official documentation](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/bootstrap/magento-modes.html) here. In development mode, static files will be generated in each request. But interceptors are created only when we run the `di:compile` command

Comment: @KeyurShah got some free time today (unexpected !!!). I spent my free time with the community :)

Comment: Good to hear that :)  @Rajeev

Comment: @RajeevKTomy magento 2 is in developer mode so do I still need to run compile?

Comment: @KeyurShah would you like to add any suggestions

Comment: @Peter Yes, you need to do. developer mode wont do compilation in each request.

Comment: please see my edit

Comment: Thank you so much both of you guys I appreciate your help .Thanks for your time.

Comment: By the way in developer mode it says "Enables automatic code compilation"

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem via belwo command hope some one help this

```
cd magento_root

      find var generated vendor pub/static pub/media app/etc -type f -exec chmod g+w {} +
      find var generated vendor pub/static pub/media app/etc -type d -exec chmod g+ws {} +
      chown -R :www-data .
      chmod u+x bin/magento
     // php bin/magento setup:di:compile
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error, after calling a helper method.

```
<referenceBlock name="category.products.list">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="test" xsi:type="helper" helper="Company\Base\Helper\Product::footest" />
    </arguments>
</referenceBlock>
```

The helper has argument name "test", but I called it like this:

**WRONG:**

```
<?php $block->footest($_product); ?>
```

**CORRECT:**

```
<?php $block->getTest($_product); ?>
```